# Page refreshing multiple time after upgrading to storybook 7 with webpack 5

Tags: webpack, storybook, webpack-5

#### Describe the bug

Page reloading in cycles after upgrading to storybook 7 with webpack 5

https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/assets/8790510/99c6345f-8c8d-4148-980d-30b810a37e7e

#### To Reproduce

It a private repo.

But I have the following configs.

main.js

```js
  framework: {
    name: '@storybook/web-components-webpack5',
    options: {
      fastRefresh: true,
      builder: { lazyCompilation: true },
    },
  },
  features: {
    postcss: false,
    /* Code splitting flag; load stories on-demand */
    storyStoreV7: true,
    /* Builds stories.json to help with on-demand loading */
    buildStoriesJson: true,
  },
  docs: {
    autodocs: true, // see below for alternatives
    defaultName: 'Docs', // set to change the name of generated docs entries
  },
```

package.json

```json
"@etchteam/storybook-addon-status": "^4.2.4",
  "@spectrum-css/component-builder": "^4.0.9",
  "@storybook/addon-a11y": "^7.0.12",
  "@storybook/addon-actions": "^7.0.12",
  "@storybook/addon-console": "^1.2.3",
  "@storybook/addon-docs": "^7.0.12",
  "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.0.12",
  "@storybook/api": "^7.0.12",
  "@storybook/client-api": "^7.0.12",
  "@storybook/components": "^7.0.12",
  "@storybook/core-events": "^7.0.12",
  "@storybook/manager-api": "^7.0.12",
  "@storybook/preview-api": "^7.0.12",
  "@storybook/theming": "^7.0.12",
  "@storybook/web-components-webpack5": "^7.0.12",
  "storybook": "^7.0.12",
  "lit": "^2.7.4",
  "lit-html": "^2.7.4",
  "style-loader": "3.3.3",
  "webpack": "^5.83.1"
```

repo:https://github.com/Rajdeepc/test-story